# Define source folder in static web module

Tags: web, intellij-idea, ide, settings

I'm trying to integrate the [FileWatcher plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7177) into my daily routine of web development.
I'd like to tell a Babel watcher to compile the file recently modified in the *src* folder to the *dist* folder, while maintaining the folder structure.

I'd use the **$FilePathRelativeToSourcepath$** macro to get the path of the file relative to the *src* folder, BUT ... from my project setup, I cannot specify the *src* folder as a Source Folder for my Static Web module.

[image: project structure panel]

Does anyone know why we can't specify that in a Static Web module?
Is it the same in WebStorm?
Can you think of a way to work around the problem? (without resorting to node file watchers and such, I'm looking for something strictly controlled by the IDE.)

And since we're at it ... how about tests folders?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to create a static web project and mark a directory as a `Sources Root` directory without any problems.

I right clicked the `src` directory and then selected `Mark Directory as` and then `Sources Root`.

[image: Show Mark Directory as Menu]

Comment: bums me out that it's not in the Project Structure window but yeah, this works! thanks